# Insert any type of text in a column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How can I insert any type of text into a column of type text?

At the moment I am using this:

```
$$description$$
```

But a lot of my descriptions contain `$` and other signs, so the insert will fail. Do I need to convert the text to something?

Comment: @aasim.abdullah: that's not the question. This refers to Postgres' "dollar quoting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not limited to just `$$` you can use anything enclosed in `$`, e.g. `$_alex_delimiter_$`

```
insert into foo 
   (some_column)
values
  ($_alex_delimiter_$this is a long string that contains a single $ and two $$ and quotes '''''$_alex_delimiter_$);
```

Just pick something that won't be part of the text.